# How to get selected rows' index in Table element in iview vue?

Tags: vue.js, html-table, iview

How to get selected rows' index in Table element in iview vue?
For example, table element is like below:

```
<Table ref="selection" :columns="columns4" :data="data1" @on-selection-change="updateSelectedNumber"></Table>
```

Comment: is it using some framework to issue the table?

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel yes, I'm using Vue and iView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET data rows item clicked.
To get the index of the item clicked, simply click on the line you want, not above the checkbox, over the item that is not the box, but that is on the same line.

add this tag

```
methods: {
 valueRowClick(value)
 console.log(value)
}
result:
position: 0 -> Object 
position 1: -> Index item clicked 2
```

When you select an item, according to the documentation it throws the value of the selected items out.
GET data item select

```
<table @on-select="nameFunction">
methods: {
 nameFunction (value) {
 console.log(value)
}
}
```

DELETE ITEM EXAMPLE:
add the this tag TABLE

```
<table @on-selection-change="valueItemsSelected"></table>
methods: {
    valueItemsSelected(value){
      if(value.length > 0){
       for(let y = 0, max1 = value.length; y < max1; y ++){
         for(let i = 0, max = this.data1.length; i < max; i++){
          if(value[y] === this.data1[i])    {
           this.data1.splice(i, 1)
          }
         }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Actually I want to do batch deletion. After selecting rows, I want to delete them one by one. It is complicated to maintain an additional array of selected tags. Is there any other more convenient way to accomplish it ?

Comment: No it's not, I'll edit my answer with an example of the requested one.
I showed the example of how to get the index.

Comment: i Add @chucklai

Comment: there maybe a little misunderstanding. I want to delete selected rows whose checkbox is checked without knowing the actually ID or other attributes.

Comment: a moment for kindness

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML template as
`<Table :columns="myColumns" :data="myData" />`
do nothing.

In your `<script>`, when you click on a row, you can get a `params` object to your function, with data structure like this:

```
{
  row : {...}
  index : 0 // or maybe the actual row index,
  column: {...}
}

rowClicked(params.index) {
  let rowIndex = params.index;
}
```